# Tips for earning the "Close encounter" achievement in Toki Tori?

Tags: toki-tori

The description is "Get really close to a monster".  But apparently I suck at playing chicken, because I die instead of earning the achievement.

What qualifies as "really close" for this?  Are there any hints as to how to achieve it?

Comment: Not sure about the achievement, as the Wii version doesn't have them, but you might try standing on one side of a gap, and letting an enemy wall over (and fall through) it.  This way, the enemy would be directly next to you.

Comment: @Katie Why the iphone tag?  I'm playing this on PC.

Comment: Apologies!  A bad assumption on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best strategy is to use the shower curtain item, makes you stationary and unable to be hurt like the tanooki suit in Super Mario 3. I think can only be used in the test lab world.

An easy way to get to the test lab world is to start a new profile and name it "potato", since it automatically opens up the world for you.